# Tap to click stopped working on 19.04

Tags: mouse, 19.04

After upgrading to 19.04 last night, tap to click no longer works on my Dell XPS 13 9350. I'm using Unity.

I tried using xinput to enable it but to no avail:

```
$ xinput list-props 11 | grep -i tap
    Synaptics Tap Time (291):   180
    Synaptics Tap Move (292):   61
    Synaptics Tap Durations (293):  180, 180, 100
    Synaptics Tap Action (305): 20, 80
```

It is also set to enabled in the mouse settings window.

Answer (score 1):

this line in my script got me the current (which as you now realise can change) xinput numbers from the names, in this case anything with ELAN0732. my results here is 14 and 15.

xinput --list  | sed -n 's/.*ELAN0732:00.*id=([0-9]*).*/\1/p'

so you can set result as a variable and setpprop from that most likely using the first one to come up, 14 for me there.

Comment: that's helpful, thanks. In case you're also on an XPS13: do you notice it being much worse at palm detection and such like? Mine seems oversensitive and isn't nearly as reliable as on Windows. (Also no pinch-to-zoom)

Comment: no I am an AMD X360 Ryzen 2500.

Comment: and in case it is useful, touchegg might assist in pinch and zoom and a lot of other stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. The xinput props setting numbers have changed once again and it turns out I had a set of ~/.profile settings that was overwriting them with funny values, which was the spanner in the works.

FYI here is what I have set now as of Ubuntu 19.04

```
xinput set-prop 11 313 20.0 50000.0  # more or less disable inertial scrolling because it just keeps sending scroll events which can lead to unwanted zooming if ctrl is pressed immediately after)  
xinput set-prop 11 311 1   # palm detection on
xinput set-prop 11 312 1, 1   # set it to the smallest area possible (dunno if this is actually effective)
```